# Compute mean within group based on condition dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am georeferencing a list of items labelled `site_vote_ID`. These are voting stations located inside cities. I follow three different strategies to locate each voting station. Each strategy gives me a latitude: `lat_ad_osm` , `lat_adp_osm`, and `lat_ocha`. For those `site_vote_ID` for which I am not able to find any latitude, I want to compute the latitude based on the average latitude of all other voting stations located in the same city for which I have a non missing latitude.

I want to do this only in cities. I identify cities by the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(clcr = c("MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
"LIKASI VILLE", "KISANGANI VILLE", "GOMA VILLE", "MBANDAKA VILLE", 
"MATADI VILLE", "KOLWEZI VILLE", "TSHIKAPA VILLE", "MWENE-DITU VILLE", 
"BENI VILLE", "KIKWIT VILLE", "BOMA VILLE", "KANANGA VILLE", 
"KINDU VILLE", "BUNIA VILLE", "BANDUNDU VILLE", "GBADOLITE VILLE", 
"ZONGO VILLE", "BUTEMBO VILLE", "BUKAVU VILLE", "ISIRO VILLE"
)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

In `dplyr` terms it should look like this (not working because `Error in grepl(ville$clcr) : argument "x" is missing, with no default` ):

```
final <- cenielecdf_ad2osm %>%
  group_by(clcr) %>%
  mutate(av_lat = ifelse(clcr == grepl(ville$clcr), mean(!is.na(c("lat_ad_osm", "lat_adp_osm", "lat_ocha"), NA))))
```

Can anyone help me here?

```
structure(list(site_vote_ID = c("810016", "710032", "710031", 
"710098", "710076", "710061", "810027", "810019", "810034", "810053", 
"810024", "810036", "710037", "810082", "710053", "710056", "810012", 
"810051", "810017", "810007", "710015", "810052", "810023", "710060", 
"810066", "810038", "710026", "540002", "540001", "540044", "810062", 
"810083", "710088", "710043", "810026", "710044", "810004", "810008", 
"710013", "810050", "810068", "810010", "810001", "710063", "810085", 
"810002", "540046", "710033", "540049", "810006", "710001", "810069", 
"810025", "810011", "810075", "810055", "710058", "540003", "810039", 
"810076", "810081", "710051", "810013", "810064", "810044", "710101", 
"610011", "810015", "710048", "710069", "710022", "810079", "810067", 
"810032", "810045", "810030", "710074", "540004", "810029", "810065", 
"810043", "810077", "810047", "810070", "810078", "810040", "810074", 
"710086", "810031", "810035", "810022", "810084", "810021", "410010", 
"810003", "810014", "810048", "710057", "810046", "710030"), 
    clcr = c("MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "LIKASI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "KISANGANI VILLE", 
    "KISANGANI VILLE", "KISANGANI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "KISANGANI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "KISANGANI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "KISANGANI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LIKASI VILLE", "GOMA VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "KISANGANI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBANDAKA VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE", 
    "MBUJI-MAYI VILLE", "LUBUMBASHI VILLE"), lat_ad_osm = c(NA, 
    -11.7062452, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -11.606679, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -11.691544, -6.1022365, 
    -6.1172396, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.1027773, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, -6.0905462, -11.678251, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -11.641348, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -11.7055366, 
    -11.6457268, -11.6125155, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.1231689, -11.6276079, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.1231689, NA, -11.6322452, 
    -6.1487845, -6.1231689, -6.1348244, NA, -6.1348244, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lat_adp_osm = c(NA, 27.4651623, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.5409463, 27.5409463, 
    NA, NA, 23.6208335, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.4643049, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 23.5780294, NA, NA, NA, 23.5792109, 27.4727149, 
    23.5792109, 23.5723995, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23.6175974, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 23.5693096, 27.4723585, 23.6082458, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 27.4847847, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.4977762, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 27.4844973, 27.5232799, 27.5010386, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 23.6175974, 27.5398971, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    23.6175974, NA, 27.5447544, 23.6208335, 23.6175974, 23.6100466, 
    NA, 23.6100466, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lat_ocha = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The expected output is a column labelled ```av_lat``` which is the average of all non-missing ```lat_ad_osm``` , ```lat_adp_osm```, and ```lat_ocha``` computed by group ```clcr```if ```clcr```in the second dataframe equals ```clcr``` in the first one. The data I provided are extracts and for example it is possible that clcr in the second dataframe is different from clcr in first dataframe. In this case ```av_lat``` should return NA.

Comment: The code for the example data is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`grepl` requires a pattern and a vector of values to check. You have only supplied a pattern in `grepl(ville$clcr)`. See `?grepl` for more help.